# Parse Objects not created from node in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform

I have the following code running on a node server @ heroku.  The trouble I am having is that the application frequently fails to create a new parse.com object on post.  What is strange is that this code works 100% of the time on my local machine.  running through heroku introduces the issue.

I run a heroku log trail when the application posts and it does not throw any exceptions/errors, so I'm stumped as to what to look for.

BTW - I realize this code isn't the prettiest, this is my first attempt to get a node/heroku/parse application up and running.

```
var http = require('http');
var url  = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var fs   = require('fs');
var Parse = require('parse/node').Parse;
var mime = require('mime');
var server = http.createServer(router).listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
Parse.initialize("key", "key");
console.log("Parse initialized");

function router (req, res) {
  var pathname = url.parse(req.url, true).pathname;
  if (pathname.slice(0, 4) === '/api') {
    apiHandler(req, res);
  } else {
    if (pathname[pathname.length - 1] === '/')
      pathname += 'index.html';
    staticFileHandler(pathname, res);
  }
}

function staticFileHandler (pathname, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public_html' + pathname, function (err, data) {
    if (err) return errHandler(err, res);
    console.log('[200]: ' + pathname);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', mime.lookup(path.extname(pathname)));
    res.end(data);
  });
}

function errHandler (err, res) {
  if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.end('File not found!');
    console.log('[404]: File not found: ' + err.path);
  } else {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

function apiHandler (req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    //send back a list of todos
    // var toDo = new Parse.Object("ToDo");
    var parseQuery = new Parse.Query("ToDo");
    parseQuery.find({
      success: function(toDoList){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', mime.lookup('json'));
        res.end(JSON.stringify(toDoList));
      },
      error: function(toDoList, error) {
        // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
        console.log('Error encountered while getting Parse objects: ' + error.message);
      }
    });

  } else if (req.method === "POST"){
      var body = "";
      req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    var today = new Date();

    req.on('end', function () {
      var toDo = new Parse.Object("ToDo");
      toDo.set('Description', body);
      toDo.set('Done', false);
      toDo.set('DueDate',today )

      toDo.save(null, {
        success: function(toDo) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
          console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + toDo.id);
        },
        error: function(toDo, error) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
          console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
        }
      });
    });

    res.end();
  }
}
```

Comment: is a proxy between client and heroku? if not, then review and verify that the POST to localhost is same as the POST to heroku... same url, same http.headers, same JSON in body of the post. If those are all the same, you should get same results.  Be aware that heroku Logs should show any errant process like timeouts etc. So you can rule that out

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/building-parse-web-apps-with-the-express-web-framework/   may want to use express

Comment: No, there is not a proxy between client and heroku.  I'll evaluate the elements you pointed out and see if I can identify a variance.

Comment: one other thing to try... your localhost may have diff parse session credentials than heroku... that could be the diff.. since its server-side code, why not set parse option for master key? That would rule out any diff in query response due to ACL variance between sessions on localhost Vs Heroku instances of node.